# Meaning of Deduplicated during Borg Create's Realtime Output

Tags: deduplication, borgbackup

When the [borg create](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html) command is used with the `--progress` argument, it output like this:

```
5.50 GB O 5.10 GB C 23.95 kB D 15600 N /path/to/current/file/being/processed
```

I was able to locate what the abbreviations above stand for [here](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html):

> The --progress option shows (from left to right) Original, Compressed
> and Deduplicated (O, C and D, respectively), then the Number of files
> (N) processed so far, followed by the currently processed path. -[source](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html)

Yet, I'm still not certain about the meaning of [Deduplicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication) as it is used here.

In the example above, Deduplicated's value is `23.95 kB`. Does that mean that out of the 5GB of data, processed so far, only 23.95 kB of it needed to be transferred because that's the only unique data found since my last archival into the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the text in the next section down (which talks about `--stats`, but which also mentions "the deduplicated size"), this is how much is actually added to the backup repository:

> When using `--stats`, you will get some statistics about how much data was added - the “This Archive” deduplicated size there is most interesting as that is how much your repository will grow.

I am not a BorgBackup user, so I don't have the means of testing this readily available, but it strikes me as something that ought to be fairly easy to test by just running two backups back-to-back, one first and then another with one large file duplicated (so that the backup contains a known duplicated set of data).

Comment: I am a Borg user and can confirm that this is accurate.

Comment: Wow. That's awesome.